# Parallax effect with multiple images partially covering each other

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm afraid this question may get down voted, but I haven't been able to find out my answer, so I'm going to ask the question.

I'm trying to create a parallax effect similar to what [this website](http://www.case-3d.com/#home) is doing. (the picture of the room with furniture). Can anybody direct me to a tutorial on this?

Looks like this is done using a lot of **Javascript**. Can this be done in **CSS** only?

Answer (score 0):

I think no, You have to use javascript.
here is agood one for it:
http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/
or
http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/

good luck!